# How to load upfront image with ng-src

Tags: angularjs

I have an api end point which return an image in response. So, I directly bind the ng-src for an image tag with my end point that looks like this

```
<img data-ng-src="https://loventedtest.appspot.com/image/255fe126-bfa8-4b7b-ac14-b53751b88470" />
```

What I am wondering is to show upfront image until the image get load from the server or keep the upfront image if the image not found on the server. I am not sure, how can I make it possible, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this <kbd>[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/k90ZyaYknxChUbuJfdk2?p=preview)</kbd> for more details.

Maybe you can resolve your problem with css. In you html :

```
<img class="img-wrapped" ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}">
```

in your css :

```
.img-wrapped {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/200x200);
}
```

For compatibility purposes (tested on Firefox too), you may wrap your img.
Markup :

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}">
</div>
```

css :

```
.img-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/200x200);
}
```

See the <kbd>[**updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hgMgHNG2bUDmbg9mVEJ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, seems little better. What happen if image failed to load from server? will the background keep remain?

Comment: absolutely. background keeps, but you anyway got a 'crashed img' icon (tested on Chrome). see the updated Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/k90ZyaYknxChUbuJfdk2?p=preview

Comment: hmm..I commented out one of the scope variable and it seems that there are no background image there. can you please check again? Thanks

Comment: Works great in chrome, but not in firefox. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you very much. That's really helpful and seems to be a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

ng-src allows you to use data binding. You can have a string called $scope.imageUrl in your controller, and use

```
 img data-ng-src="{{imageUrl}}"
```

in your html file. You can then change that variable's value in your controller and it will change that image automatically.

Comment: I think, you did not get it. I don't need to set any property in the controller for ng-src. I can directly set the url in ng-src like the example I showed in my question.

Comment: Having it as a variable makes it easier for you to change it dynamically. Now, what do you mean exactly with "loading the image from the server"? Do you mean, after it's rendered on the client's browser? Can you explain a little more this use case, or even better, show us an example of how are you loading that image?

Comment: Look I have an end point which return me the image id, so I set the property in the controller and on the view I bind it like ng-src="https://loventedtest.appspot.com/images/{{vm.imageId}}"... So it will load the image from the server. The call is async so I don't know when I will have an image, in the mean time how would I set the upfront image or keep it if there is no image found on the server? Notice, I can not set the full image Url in a property because there would be many images and they all have the same base url, so I only set imageId property. Make sense?

Comment: what about using ng-show? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow  You can have a placeholder url, and use ng-hide/ng-show with the value of vm.imageId, which would be falsey while the info is not loaded.

Comment: I already have imageId property value when view activated, it just take time to load image from server. That's why I need placeholder, I don't think ng-show/ng-hide would be helpful